# What does this mean/do? "value < 0 ? -value : value;"

Tags: c#, properties

In C#

A book I am following advises this for set and get properties:

```
double pri_test;

public double Test
{
    get { return pri_test; }
    set { pri_test = value < 0 ? -value : value; }
}
```

I understand what `value` is doing, its the input value from something outside using the property, however I don't understand the use of `-value` and the `?` symbol and `:`

Could someone explain what this means: `value < 0 ? -value : value`?

Comment: Apart from the correct answers you've already got, it is a completely useless ternary operator which could be replaced with `pri_test = Math.Abs(value);`

Comment: Also, it's not nice to write properties so that `x.Property = y; Debug.Assert(x.Property == y);` fails. If you're going to do that, make it a method call, not a property.

Comment: ...and also, this setter implementation violates design guidelines. Consider this code: `double v = -1; someInstance.Test = v; Debug.WriteLine(v == someInstance.Test);`.

Comment: The fact that this is written in a book, which presumably had technical editors is a good indication of a bad book!

Comment: Cheers guys, I'll keep in mind that this is a bad practice. The book was written for C# version 3 so perhaps this explains why they decided this code?

Comment: @Joseph - unlikely, `Math.Abs` has been part of the framework since [vn 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the conditional operator. 
See [`?: Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`?: (Wikipedia)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#C.23) (the latter link is very concise!)

You'll often see people refer to the conditional operator it as *the* ternary operator. This is because a ternary operator takes three operands in this case -  the condition, and two expressions.

---

Pertaining to `-value`, the prefix `-` meerly negates the integer

```
int bar = 10;
int foo  = -bar;
Console.Write(foo); //prints "-10".
```

Comment: And possibly referred to as "the" because it's the only ternary operator in C#. But yes. It is most definitely named the conditional operator. =)

Answer (score 4):

From [`?: Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

> The `condition` must evaluate to `true` or `false`. If `condition` is `true`,
>   `first_expression` is evaluated and becomes the result. If `condition` is
>   `false`, `second_expression` is evaluated and becomes the result.

```
pri_test = value < 0 ? -value : value;
```

is equivalent to;

```
if( value < 0 )
{
   pri_test = -value;
}
else
{
   pri_test = value;
}
```

Comment: Note that `?:` operator is not equivalent to `if-else` statement, even though in this question, they have the same result.

Comment: @DannyChen Of course _not exactly_ the equivalent. The ternary operator initialize a variable with the result of the expression. In compile-time, the C# compiler translates the ternary expression into branch statements. Like [`brtrue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue.aspx)

Comment: @SonerGönül, you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue.aspx, seeing as this is an English speaking site.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Yeah, since because I'm from Turkey, when I open any MSDN page, default language is Turkish.

Answer (score 4):

You've already gotten a few answers pointing you to the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that accounts for half your question

> Could someone explain what this means? `value < 0 ? -value : value`

What that line is doing with `value` is checking if it is negative, and if so turning it to a positive. If the value starts off positive, it just leaves it alone.

There is already a method in the .NET framework which does this: [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx). So that line could be re-written as

```
  pri_test = Math.Abs(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is used to take the absolute value of a number. So if the number is negative. They take the number negated, that results in the positive number ( minus multiplied by minus is plus).

The other answers deal with the ?: ternary operator, but I would change the code to read like this in the setter:

```
set { pri_test = Math.Abs(value); }
```

Much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
value < 0 ? -value : value
```

is equals to this

```
if(value < 0) 
{

   pri_test = -value;

}
else
{
   pri_test = value;
}
```